# Hover Dropdown Menu using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I have downloaded a boostrap template online and is making modifications to the template. However, I'd like my menu bar to hoverable dropdowns for each item in the menu bar. I have this for the css of the dropdown:

```
.dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

This is the html part:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto dropdown">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Services</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#experts">Experts</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#">Test dropdown</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have been just following instructions online but I can't seem to get it right.

This is the output that I kept on getting:

[image: Output]

It shows the submenu even if the cursor is not hovering over the menu.

Comment: Do you want it to only display when you hover over the `Experts` link?

Comment: Yes I would like to make it work with one item first

Comment: I was going to say that you need to add the `dropdown` class to the relevant `li` and specify that you need `.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-content` instead of `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content`, but I see that @HasuKimchi has beaten me to it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you forgot to add the `dropdown`class to your `nav-item`:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Services</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#experts">Experts</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#">Test dropdown</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And then you need to specify the direct child with `>` in if you hover selector.

```
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-content {display: block;}
```

Comment: At first it didn't work, but upon checking my css files I've noticed that there are two similar css there and I was only applying changes to one. I tried applying same changes to the other one and it worked! Thank you!